# gstreamer pipeline code to display text over live streaming from camera and not image?

Tags: c++, c, text, gstreamer

Can any one please suggest a working pipeline to display text over live streaming using v4l2src and mfw_isink ?

I have a working pipeline to display textoverlay, clockoverlay, timeoverlay but with test source and and test sink and not with desired source and sink.

```
gst-launch videotestsrc pattern=blue ! textoverlay font-desc="San 32" text="CAM1 Disconnected" valign=top halign=left ! ximagesink
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace your elements with needed ones, and insert `videoconvert` if needed. I suggest you to learn how to write pipeline description, however.

Here I replaced `videotestsrc` with `v4l2src` and put `videoconvert` element because `v4l2src` and `ximagesink` has no common video format in their list of supported formats to use together.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! textoverlay font-desc="San 32" text="CAM1 Disconnected" ! ximagesink
```

I used GStreamer 1.x here.

You can replace `ximagesink` with with your custom sink.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kyrylo